# WSHShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings with limited priviledges

Tags: shell, vbscript, environment-variables

I must run a script on user accounts with limited privileges. In the script, there's a line that find the full path of a file specified and it must work with environment variables, for example %HOMEDRIVE%.

However, the command line

```
objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%HOMEDRIVE%")
```

throws an acess denied exception if the user is not an administrator.

How can I read this environment variable from an account with limited privledges?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide more context and the exact error details (error number, message, line number). That line you posted should not raise "access denied" errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try  putting the following at the start of your script:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strHomeFolder = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%")
Const ssfPROFILE = &H28
Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
strHomeFolder = oShell.NameSpace(ssfPROFILE).Self.Path
```

Then, when you need to reference the username you can use the following instead of "C:\Users...\" just put in:

```
= strHomeFolder & "\...\The Rest Of The Filepath eg.appdata\...\"
```

This should let you access the user-specific path and then continue on to find a specific file. It accesses which ever user who is logged in's home folder. If another user opens it it will access his/her homefolder instead.

I hope this helps!

Comment: This code also breaks on .ExpandEnvironmentStrings with the "access denied error" on non-admin accounts. It looks like a standard user cannot access environment variables.